# Issue while creating the Foreign Key Constraint : MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Category Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcategory` (
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_tblcategory_Category` (`Category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

**Sub Category Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblsubcategory` (
  `SubCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SubCategory` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SubCategoryID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_tblSubCategory_SubCategory_CategoryID` (`CategoryID`,`SubCategory`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

**Below is the Query I tried to add Foreign key Reference in Sub Catgeory Table**

```
ALTER TABLE tblsubcategory
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tblsubcategory_tblcategory_CategoryID
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID)
REFERENCES tblsubcategory(CategoryID)
```

**MySQL said**

> ## 1005 - Can't create table `myapp`.`#sql-6b8_33` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

**Question**

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to reference `CategoryID` in the **other** table...

```
ALTER TABLE tblsubcategory
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tblsubcategory_tblcategory_CategoryID
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID)
REFERENCES tblcategory(CategoryID)
```

Comment: Don't worry about it. Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes to see the problem. We've all been there.

Comment: I think following the rules and waiting would be a good idea if it's a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference `Category` table, not the `SubCategory` table:

```
ALTER TABLE tblsubcategory
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tblsubcategory_tblcategory_CategoryID
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID)
REFERENCES tblcategory(CategoryID)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```